# C# Repositioning Columns

Tags: c#, dataset

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Sr.No.",typeof(int)));
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    dr["Sr.No."] = c.ToString();
    c++;
}
ds.Tables[0].Columns["Sr.No."].SetOrdinal(0);
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

The following code returns a nullreferenceexception for setordinal().

Comment: Can't reproduce, are you sure that you haven't any event raised when you bind your data? What happen if (for testing) your comment out the DataBinding commands?

Comment: Can't reproduce too. Can you add full exception text?